# Azure Web App stop working with sites.config file was changed by another program

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

my web app stop working after running well couple of days with below exception in the log file.
And it will start to work after I saved the web.config file even without changing anything in it.
Then stop working again with another random days running well.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

> 2017-06-15 17:00:19,120 [8] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default
>   (null)
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The configuration file has been changed by another program. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\Config\Sites.config)
>   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
>   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
>   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
>   at Autofac.Configuration.SectionHandler.Deserialize(String configurationFile, String configurationSection)
>   at Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContainerFactory.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__2(ContainerBuilder builder)
>   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.CreateScopeRestrictedRegistry(Object tag, Action1 configurationAction) at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(Object tag, Action1 configurationAction)
>   at Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings)
>   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.b__31_1(ShellSettings settings)

Comment: Is the Sites.config file under D:\home\site\wwwroot\Config? Is it a ASP.NET Web application? Could you share us the project (which will help reproduce the problem)?

Comment: Yes, the sites.config file is under wwwroot\Config folder, it's a normal web app. Unfortunately I couldn't share the project since it's not public.
Yes, the sites.config file is under wwwroot\Config folder, it's a normal web app. Unfortunately I couldn't share the project since it's not public.

I found I can reproduce the error by updating the App Service Plan manually, it will crash every time when I change the App Service Plan, restart doesn't help, only update the web.config can help make it work.

Comment: Found one useful link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b185de7-dcdd-4046-bec1-e617da7b5d21/azure-web-app-could-not-find-existent-path-or-file?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview, and add the WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE helps, it's said there is a bug caching the file, is this fixed?

Comment: Does adding an app setting named WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE solve the problem? If you remove this app setting, does same error appear?

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. Removed this setting is causing the web app error again when updating the Web App service plan.